# Windows is showing two icons for each file in search. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-search

I've made a search in Local Disk to find all my PDF files. When the search concluded, each file has two icons.

Screenshot to illustrate the problem:

[image]

When I click in one of the "pair of files" both are selected, and I can't unselect one of them. When I click in Properties, it not shows "two files", instead  it shows the properties for the file, like its location.

The "duplicated" files are not links, and when I click in 'Open file location', I'm redirected to the same folder.

My question is: Why is this occurring?

Comment: Did your restart your computer (should always be the 1st troubleshooting step)?

Comment: Yes. And did an sfc /scannow, dism /RestoreHealth and Rebuild Index

Comment: I would start by resetting Explorer to it's default settings. Open Explorer -> View tab -> Options -> (for the General, View and Search tabs) Restore Defaults -> Apply -> OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset Explorer to it's default settings:

- Open Explorer
- View tab
- Options
- (for the General, View and Search tabs) Restore Defaults
- Apply
- OK